# show/view indexes in database MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm using MySQL.
Is there any way to see all the indexes in a list on a particular database ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.STATISTICS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html

To get all indexes for a given database use:

```
select * from information_schema.statistics
```

Comment: i want to get a list of all indexes in a database not in a table

Answer (score 1):

For all indexes of a database you have to read from information_schema.STATISTICS:

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.STATISTICS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this

```
SELECT DISTINCT    TABLE_NAME,    INDEX_NAME
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema';
```